# How to reactivate Win 10 without microsoft account

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation, product-key

I recently upgraded the hardware of my PC and afterwards my Win 10 was deactivated. I do not have it linked to a Microsoft account.

Which options do I have to activate it again?

Further information: The Win 10 license is an upgraded Win 7 license from which I still have the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Upgrades from Windows 7 receive a Digital License](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activation).

If you ever entered a Microsoft account, your digital license may have been associated with that account automatically. If this is the case, then you might be able to use the Activation Troubleshooter to reactivate (assuming you have Windows 10 Anniversary or above). Otherwise, you may need to call Microsoft Customer Support.

**Additional Information**

Starting with Windows 10 Version 1511, it's apparently (potentially) possible to [use a Windows 7, 8 or 8.1 key to activate Windows 10](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/617750/activate-windows-10-using-windows-7-8-or-81-product-key/) in upgrades (though this excludes Volume, Multiple Activation or Enterprise Licenses).

Comment: I never had a microsoft account which it could have been connected with. So only option is the customer support?

Comment: I've seen it being used in kinda every guide now and I haven't found any other solution myself. Do you know the time in which I can reach out to the support? I live in Germany (GMT+1)

Comment: If my math isn't too off, you should be fine (assuming you call the US toll free number) in a little over an hour (5AM PST/ 2PM CET) at +1-800-642-7676. They also have an online contact page at https://partner.support.services.microsoft.com/en-us/contact/menu/software/windows/setup/

Comment: Windows 7 isn’t a digital license at least not like Windows 8 or the digital entitlement that Windows 10 has

Comment: @Ramhound So if OP upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, he can re-enter the Windows 7 key to reactivate Windows 10?

Comment: I wrote with the support and they told me to run "slui 3" and enter my Win 7 product key, which I gave them earlier. I assume, they "upgraded" my key from win 7 to win 10. I couldn't try it yet

Comment: The license key isn’t required to be provided to Windows 10 if it’s been installed on the device before.  So it absolutely is not required to provide the Windows 7 to reactiave Windows 10.  I have written dozens of answers on how Windows 10 activation works.

Answer (score 4):

Recently I came across this and got the following info from Microsoft for anyone with the same issue:

- Right click **Start** and run PowerShell.
- Type `slmgr.vbs /upk` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will disassociate the product key from your old machine. Then, go back to the *Windows Activation* and enter your same product key and it should now work.

Comment: Would this need to be executed on the old machine?

Comment: This worked flawlessly for me. I ran it on the PC _after_ replacing the motherboard (Windows was then asking for activation). I then used "Change product key" under Activation settings, entered my Window 7 Pro Retail key and chose to activate.

Comment: Didn't work for me. However it turned out that this has been a Windows 8 key. They can be used for Windows 10 but not for reactivation after a hardware change. At least that's what the MS Support told me.